# Only KQL is available in Kibana Discover Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I added an index pattern in Kibana for the elastic search index and executed some transactions multiple times.

But I cannot see the time range histogram or any option to select in the Discover dashboard.

Pls, refer following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Based on the availability of @timestamp field, It seems you are adding a timeseries logs to Elasticsearch.
Recreate the index pattern again by referring to the following link and I believe the issue will be fixed:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html#_create_an_index_pattern_for_time_series_data
Also, a similar problem is mentioned here:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/time-picker-is-not-showing-in-kibana/100698
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/no-timepicker-shown-despite-date-field-is-recognized-correctly/90534

Comment: Thanks recreating index pattern with @timestamp field, resolved the issue

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate index pattern with @timestamp field after deleting the existing index pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the availability of @timestamp field, It seems you are adding a timeseries logs to Elasticsearch. Recreate the index pattern again by referring to the following link and I believe the issue will be fixed: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html#_create_an_index_pattern_for_time_series_data